# How can I disable Riddler's Proximity Mines?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

In Batman: Arkham City, some Riddler trophies are found behind ***Riddler's Proximity Mines***. When Batman gets close, they explode. These mines must be disabled in order to reach those trophies. I use *Detective Mode* to discover if they are connected to any mechanism, but they seem not to be connected to any mechanism.

How can I disable *Riddler's Proximity Mines*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to have the Disruptor with the Mine Detonator. [From IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/batman-arkham-city/Mine_Detonator):

> Received for completing the Remote Hideaway side mission, the Mine
>   Detonator allows you to detonate mines from a distance and locate
>   Riddler Trophies.

Comment: It's also important to note that a lot of the mines do NOT need to be detonated to get the trophies, and are only intended to mislead the player.  Only mines in the mazes that you walk directly over must be detonated - you can walk right next to one without triggering an explosion