# How can I disable the Riddler Proximity Mine in the Secret Corridor in Wonder City?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I've been playing Batman: Arkham City and there is a *Riddler Proximity Mine* in the Secret Corridor in Wonder City. I've tried to disable it using the **Disruptor** (as suggested in the answer to my previous [question about disabling Proximity Mines](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39210/how-can-i-disable-riddlers-proximity-mines)) but it doesn't work (I'm aiming with LT and pressing RT, but there comes the "no sign" [image]).

I've also tried to find a way to that room which stores the Riddler Trophy, but to no avail (I've taken a look inside the room by throwing a remote batarang in it).

The only way in seems to slide under the bars but the mine must be disabled first. How can I achieve this?

Below are two images I took with my good old cellphone. Sorry for the low image quality.

[image: corridor]
[image: map]
[image: disruptor]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The disruptor's the correct tool to use here.  Perhaps you're just not hitting the mine with it properly?  Do you have the upgrade which lets you [detonate the mines](http://www.ign.com/wikis/batman-arkham-city/Mine_Detonator)?  You'll have to hold the detonate button down (R2 on the PS3) in order to get it to explode.

You get this upgrade from:

> the cops in the Iceberg Lounge, during the side mission [Remote Hideaway](http://www.ign.com/wikis/batman-arkham-city/Remote_Hideaway).

Comment: I have got the Disruptor. Please see my edit.

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar Do you also have the Mine Detonator upgrade?

Comment: I've checked the gadgets; Mine Detonator upgrade isn't present. I thought I finished that side mission but apparently I did not. Thanks for your help.